# move from one form to another but stop the code of the first form

Tags: c#

I am working on my project. Basically i have 3 forms now i want to do the following steps

1. Move from first form to the second
2. Then come back to the first form again when second form is closed but it should be at that
   line of code where it was before when going to the second form.
3. Then show the third form.

Kindly Help 
Regards 
Hammad

Comment: ShowDialog...did you try google...research modal dialogs?

Comment: no i havent but yes its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way...

```
// ... in Form1 ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog(); // code stops here until "f2" is closed
Form3 f3 = new Form3();
f3.Show();
```